# How to delete all the nodes registered for a project in Rundeck using REST API

Tags: rundeck

I am new to rundeck and for one of my usecase i need to delete all the nodes registered for a project using REST API endpoint.So just wanted to check is there any endpoint that rundeck provides that i can reuse.
Thanks
-Sam

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not. just remove the node resource files for that project

[Node Sources](http://rundeck.org/docs/administration/managing-node-sources.html)